# How To send/receive data from Web App (php) to C# Windows app

Tags: c#, php, windows, laravel, xampp

I want to send data from my WebApp ( **php  running in xampp** ) to  **C# Windows app** and **receive response**  **both apps are running on the same machine** .

Please help me.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of implementing this:

- If both apps are running on the same machine, you can consider using inter-process communication, e.g. [named pipe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx), [shared memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx)

[image]

- If both apps are running on different servers, consider using [message queues](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjTlLbIvvLYAhVG57wKHQtWDzsQFgguMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cloudamqp.com%2Fblog%2F2014-12-03-what-is-message-queuing.html&usg=AOvVaw2Bc1-aXFY9pBc0rAkeMG0f), where one serves as publisher, and the other end as subscriber. Example of this kind of Queues include RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ, Redis etc.

[image]